# How to change the email language format based on locale?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am having different locales for countries, i am able to translate words for others but how to translate it for mailers?

application.rb:

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
config.i18n.default_locale = 'en'
config.i18n.available_locales = ['en', 'fr']
```

config/locales/mailers/en.yml:

```
en:
  report_mailer:
    report_review:
      subject: 'Proof:'
```

config/locales/mailers/fr.yml:

```
fr:
  report_mailer:
    report_review:
      subject: 'ÉPREUVE:'
```

In application.rb file, I am mentioning locales as:

```
config.i18n.available_locales = ['en', 'fr']
config.i18n.fallbacks = { 'fr' => 'en'}
```

In case of mail, I could not translate when locale is set to *fr*, still it is taking to *en*.

app/mailers/report_mailer.rb:

```
class ReportMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  after_filter :set_delivery_options
  def set_delivery_options
    if @sender and @sender.use_smtp_settings?
      message.delivery_method.settings.merge!(@sender.smtp_settings.to_settings)
    end
  end
end
```

app/mailers/report_mailer.rb:

```
class ReportMailer < ClientMailer
  def client_review(review, requestor, reviewer)
    @review       = review
    @sender       = requestor
    @reviewer     = reviewer 
      mail(
        to:      @reviewer.email,
        subject: t('report_mailer.report_review.subject',
        job:     review.job.name
      ) if !@reviewer.email.nil? && @reviewer.email != ''
  end
end
```

One of my senior suggested to add  *I18n.default_locale = @sender.account.locale* or something like that set_delivery_options to ReportMailer. But didn't helped me.
So please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16049411/163640 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/11248315/163640 answer similar questions.

Comment: @eugen - Thanks for the links. I tried but no use. I added application.rb, please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use I18n.with_locale method

```
I18n.with_locale('en') do
  mail(
    to: @reviewer.email,
    subject: I18n.t('report_mailer.report_review.subject'
  )
end
```

I used english language but you just have to use the reviewer`s set on the database

Comment: THanks for the answer, I  tried it as **@reviewer.available_locales** but didn't helped me. I added application.rb file, please help me :)